# Devise login validation failure

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I rails3.0.4 and devise installed with following users table

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "crypted_password",         :null => false
    t.string   "password_salt",            :null => false
    t.string   "persistence_token",        :null => false
    t.string   "single_access_token",      :null => false
    t.string   "perishable_token",         :null => false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "database_authenticatable", :null => false
    t.string   "recoverable"
    t.string   "rememberable"
    t.string   "trackable"
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
  end
```

The users table was not created by devise but I added the necessary
columns in migration.
And following settings in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :email]
```

But every time I try to sign up as a new user it throws:

```
  2 errors prohibited this user from being saved:
  Login is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
  Login should use only letters, numbers, spaces, and .-_@ please.
```

Any ideas why it could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the login is too short and/or contains the wrong characters :)
You enabled the devise built-in validations, and that's what they validate. To use your own validations remove :validatable from your devise inclusion in app/models/user.rb

If you're interested, the validation used by devise is defined in lib/devise/models/validatable.rb in the devise gem.

Should the validation not be the problem you'll have to show the log of a user creation request, so that we can see what parameters are submitted.

**EDIT:** Oh I see, I misread - it's about "login". Well, see comments below.

Comment: That's what log says from log/development.log<pre>
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Mar 05 18:57:34 +0600 2011
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign up", "authenticity_token"=>"tA88vTZRWYNPRgbCv2UF65RlUJA8JEjIOaOTGif8jz8=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223", "user"=>{"password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"administrator", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"admin@email.com"}}
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: login
</pre>

Comment: "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: login". In app/models/user.rb add :login to attr_accessible